# Python Markdown: Markdown Inside HTML Blocks

Tags: python, html, markdown

Is there an extra for Python Markdown that supports Markdown inside HTML block elements, e.g. div, p

i.e. is there a way to convert this:

```
<div id="content">
    [Google](http://www.google.com)
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="content">
    <a href="http://www.google.com>Google</a>
</div>
```

using Python Markdown or a Python Markdown extension?
I'm looking for something similar to [this feature in PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/#markdown-attr)

Answer (score 4):

The relevant bug report states that the extra extension adds that: https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/issues/80

Then you can add markdown="1" to div tags to have markdown parsed inside

```
<div markdown="1">
*markdown*
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to this: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html

You would have to use a <span> rather than a <div>.  Further explanation is available at the above link.

Answer (score 0):

With [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/) (not Python, I know, but relevant), you can do this by adding the attribute `markdown=1` to the block-level element in question.

I’m interested in pure-Python libraries that support the “Markdown Extra” syntax as well.

Of course, one very workable hack would be call out to PHP & PHP Markdown Extra via standard input, from your Python script.

Comment: See https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/blob/master/docs/extensions/extra.txt and https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/issues/52